# Multiple VBO Multiple Draws - not working

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, vbo

In my opengl es 2.0 application, I have 2 primitives.
For the first primitives,
I am creating a vbo for vertices interleaved with color and another vbo for indices.

I am binding the vbos of the first primitive and enable the vertexattribarray and call drawelements.
Then, I update mvp with translation and bind the vbos for second primitive and enable the vertexattribarray and call drawelements for the second primitive.

But only the first primitive is rendered.

```
// pseudo code sequence.
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, PrimitiveONE_VBOVertexId);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_POS_INDX);
glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_POS_INDX, VERTEX_POS_SIZE, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, vtxStride, 0);
offset += (VERTEX_POS_SIZE * sizeof ( GLfloat ));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_COLOR_INDX);
glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_COLOR_INDX, VERTEX_NORMAL_SIZE, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, vtxStride, offset);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, PrimitiveOne_VBOIndexId);     
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN,  indices1Cnt, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,0); // unbind vbo
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);

glDeleteBuffers(1, &PrimitiveONE_VBOVertexId);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &PrimitiveOne_VBOIndexId);
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
myIdentity(mvp);
myIdentity(modelview);
myTranslate(modelview, 0.25f, 0 , -2.0f);
myMultMatrix(mvp, modelview, projection);
glUniformMatrix4fv(mvp_pos, 1, GL_FALSE, &mvp[0][0]);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, PrimitiveTWO_VBOVertexId);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_POS_INDX);
glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_POS_INDX, VERTEX_POS_SIZE, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, vtxStride, 0);
offset += (VERTEX_POS_SIZE * sizeof ( GLfloat ));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_COLOR_INDX);
glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_COLOR_INDX, VERTEX_NORMAL_SIZE, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, vtxStride, offset);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, c);   
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN,  indices2Cnt, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,0); // unbind vbo
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);

glDeleteBuffers(1, &PrimitiveTWO_VBOVertexId);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &PrimitiveTWO_VBOIndexId);
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Is there any issue with the code?

Comment: Some things that look potentially harmful, but it's hard to tell if any of it is the main problem: Is `offset` reset to 0 somewhere in the middle in code we don't see? It should be. You use `VERTEX_NORMAL_SIZE` for setting up the color attribute. The name suggests that it might be the wrong value. Your element buffer id for the second call is `c`, which does not match your other naming at all. Is it the right value? Strange that you delete all the buffers after drawing. Are you only drawing once?

Comment: It wasn't clear from your description: Is the second primitive rendering if you don't render the first one? Otherwise, it could be a lot of things. Bad coordinates. Transformations that do not put the coordinates into the view volume. Etc.

Comment: As Reto said, is there somewhere in your code a reset of the offset variable? In the pseudo code you presented you increase the second time (primitive) based on the result of the increase you do on the first primitive.